# Trigger Syntax mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

I want to make the Total column receive the total sum between the other columns, but i keeping getting the error 1193.
I'm new to mySql so i dont know where i should start looking to solve the error.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Total
BEFORE INSERT ON `despesas` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET Total = Abertura_Processo+Telefone+Correspondencia+Cartorio+Conservatorio+Servico_Financas+Taxas_Emolumentos+Honorarios;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I've read a bit and for what i've understood I need to create a variable, but i dont know how.
[The total column has its values manually inserted i want it to be automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4Z58.png)

Comment: What do you want to do with the total value?

Comment: I want to have the total value inserted into the database on the column total, so i can search for it. For example I searched for the payement with Id=1 with where Abetura_Processo=10 and Telefone=10 and so on, then i want the total column to be equal to 80.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reference the newly inserted record's field via `NEW.column_name` in the before insert trigger. By setting a value to such a column, you can change the value being inserted. So, change the value setting line as follows:

```
SET NEW.Total = NEW.Abertura_Processo+NEW.Telefone+NEW.Correspondencia+NEW.Cartorio+NEW.Conservatorio+NEW.Servico_Financas+NEW.Taxas_Emolumentos+NEW.Honorarios;
```

Note, you may use [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) as an alternative to this trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, every thing worked fine.